# Weight distribution and URL rewrite for a weight distribution scenario

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy

It's a rather weird scenario that I am having trouble solving but I will try to explain to the best of my ability:

An user makes a request to `ABCDE.MY_DOMAIN.com/login.html` and I want this request to be redirected to 2 different services(one that I own and another one I don't) using a weight distribution algorithm. Because this request gets redirected to 2 different services they will need to have it's URL rewritten for each one and the URI for one:

- one service will use `CUSTOM_DOMAIN_1/login.html?QUERY=true/ABCDE`
- another service will use the same URL:
  `ABCDE.MY_DOMAIN.com/login.html`

I have an haproxy sitting in front which receives all the requests and then forwards it to a *backend* but the problem that I see with using an haproxy here is that I need to have either the same path or the same url available on each one of them(I can not forward to a server in a backend pool with a certain path and to another one with a different one).

I also thought using an ALB and making a rule on the listeners but the problem is that the service running on `CUSTOM_DOMAIN_1` is not owned by me,not in my VPC, and it has a CDN in front of it so that didn't get me anywhere

Any ideas what else I could to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared any HAProxy information like version and config snipplet can I only refer to the latest HAProxy version and some config snipplets.

You can use the [srv_weight](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.2-srv_weight) for backend decision and change the http-request per backend section. This setup is not tested but I hope you get the idea.

```
frontend main

  acl cust-backend srv_weight(custom-domain/<server>) gt 5
  acl my-domain srv_sess_rate(my-domain/<server>) gt 10
  use_backend custom-domain if cust-backend
  use_backend custom-domain if my-domain


backend custom-domain
  # set header to the custom domain
  # ABCDE.MY_DOMAIN.com =>CUSTOM_DOMAIN_1
  http-request set-header Host CUSTOM_DOMAIN_1

  # set query string based on first subdomain
  # CUSTOM_DOMAIN_1/login.html?QUERY=true/ABCDE
  http-request set-var(req.subdomain) req.fhdr(host),word(1,.)
  http-request set-query QUERY=true/%[var(req.subdomain)]

  # some other backend settings with servers
  

backend my-domain
  # no changes necessary here
  # some other backend settings with servers
```

Here the documentation links for the directives above

[http-request set-header](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-header)
[http-request set-var](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-var)
[http-request set-query](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-query)
[srv_weight](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.2-srv_weight)